# Kotlin: generic cast function parameter

Tags: kotlin

Taking my first steps in Kotlin, I'm struggling to find the correct signature for a function that receives an instance of a known class along with the desired output class and then looks in a map of converter lambdas whether the conversion can be done.

Here's an example for `Long`:

```kotlin
    private fun <T> castLong(value: Long, clazz: Class<out T>): T {
        // map lookup removed for simplicity
        return when (clazz) {
            String::class.java -> { value.toString() }
            else -> { throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Cast") }
        }
    }
```

Where `T` is the class of the desired return value - let's say `String`. One should be able to call `castLong(aLongValue, String::class.java)` and receive an instance of `String`.
But the compiler says:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is String but T was expected

This seems like it should be possible as it is quite straightforward so far but even playing around with `reified` and other constructs didn't yield any better results.

Comment: You have to add an unsafe cast on value returned by your function: `return when(clazz) { ... } as T` and it will compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because it can't smart cast `String` to `T`, you have to manually cast it.

Furthermore, since you said you are taking your first steps in Kotlin, I leave here two other "advices" not strictly related to your question:

1. you can get the class of `T` making it `reified`
2. the brackets of a case using `when` aren't necessary if the case is one line

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified T> castLong(value: Long): T {
    // map lookup removed for simplicity
    return when (T::class.java) {
        String::class.java -> value.toString()
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Cast")
    } as T
}
```

Comment: Making this entire function inline is very bad idea; it should at most be an overload/alias that returns `castLong(value, T::class.java)` or it will generate insane amounts of garbage bytecode.

Comment: @Pawel I don't agree on "it's a very bad idea" and here's why. I don't know how much complex is the real code of the person who asked this question. For the example he made, making it `inline` won't produce any noticeable difference. I'd say it's an early optimization to not make it `inline` or to use an overload. It's like saying "Don't use `list.filter { }.forEach { }` since it's more performant "list.forEach { if(filter) { } }`". If the asker will see a noticeable difference on his real use-case, he can make it more performant after.

Comment: Only relevant argument is the class object so injecting bytecode of entire function into more than 1 calling place is not optimal. But still I think function like that shouldn't exist in the first place, there should be an overload for each possible "cast" to provide compile time safety.

Comment: To get "insane amounts of garbage bytecode" you need to have insane amounts of calls to this function, which is really unlikely if it's private.